# Python Selenium find Button with innterHTML and click it

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to find the following button and click it:

```
<div id="subText" class="btn btn-success">Subscribe</div>
```

I already tried to find the button with the following:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.btn.btn-success').click()
```

but I get the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <div id="subText" class="btn btn-success">...</div> is not clickable at point (408, 513). Other element would receive the click: <div class="delete-overlay white" style="">...</div>
```

Is there a way to search only for the button with the "Subscribe" text and click it?

---

Edit:
I found out that the following element is blocking the button from beeing clicked:

```
<svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-spinner-third fa-w-16 fa-spin fa-4x" aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="spinner-third" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="M456.433 371.72l-27.79-16.045c-7.192-4.152-10.052-13.136-6.487-20.636 25.82-54.328 23.566-118.602-6.768-171.03-30.265-52.529-84.802-86.621-144.76-91.424C262.35 71.922 256 64.953 256 56.649V24.56c0-9.31 7.916-16.609 17.204-15.96 81.795 5.717 156.412 51.902 197.611 123.408 41.301 71.385 43.99 159.096 8.042 232.792-4.082 8.369-14.361 11.575-22.424 6.92z"></path></svg>
```

Is there a way to wait/stop the script until the elemen/script is gone and continue?

I also tried to wait until the "Subscribe" button is visible but that didn't work:

```
sbutton = expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.btn.btn-success'))
WebDriverWait(driver, timeout_limit).until(sbutton)
```

Comment: Try `driver.find_element_by_id('subText').click()`

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention that there are multiple elements with the id "subText"

Comment: is there an url to test with?

Answer (score 0):

As per the message `<div class="delete-overlay white" style="">...</div>` is overlapped so the script is not able to click on the `<div id="subText" class="btn btn-success">Subscribe</div>` button.

Here are the options to handle this situation.

**1) Using JavaScript:**

```
ele = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "'div.btn.btn-success")))
driver.execute_script("arugments[0].click()",ele)
```

**2) Scrolling to Element**

```
ele = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "'div.btn.btn-success")))
ele.location_once_scrolled_into_view # this will scroll to the element
ele.click()
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer.
Unfortunately this doesn't work neither because sometimes it seems like another element (probably javascript) is blocking the button from beeing clicked.
Is there is possible to tell the selenium script to wait until this element/script is gone?

Comment: Added `EC.element_to_be_clickable` expected condition. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: I changed the code as you have mentioned above but on the following line:
`WebDriverWait(driver, timeout_limit).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable(sbutton))`
I get this error:
`return driver.find_element(*by)`
`TypeError: find_element() argument after * must be an iterable, not WebElement`

Comment: The updated version again gives me an error I wasn't able to solve:
    `ele = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.btn.btn-success'))
TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`

Comment: Here is the documentation link for more information [WebDriverWait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)